# my chat client is only connecting to local host

Tags: java, sockets, client, localhost, chat

I have coded the following client which is only connecting to the local host, the ip on which the machine is connected, but not a server running on different ip on a different machine. 
The error I get when I connect to outside is Connection refused
How to make it connect outside local host?

My code is as follows

```
public ChatClient(JTextField address, JTextField port, JTextField user,
        JTextField text, JTextArea tapane3, JTextArea tapane4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.address=address;
    this.user=user;
    this.text=text;
    this.port=port;
    add=address.getText();
    textarea=tapane3;
    showusers=tapane4;
}

public void sendToPort(String str) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = null;

    //String str = "Hello World";
    try {
        out.write(str, 0, str.length());
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Send")) 
    {

        try {
            textarea.append(SendMessage()+"\n");
            System.out.println(SendMessage());
            sendToPort("x");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Connect")) 
    {

        try {
            String prt=port.getText();

            cs = new Socket(add, Integer.parseInt(prt));
            out =new OutputStreamWriter(cs.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

            showusers.setText(user.getText());

            //sendToPort(Integer.parseInt(prt), Address); 




        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Disconnect")) 
    {


        try {
            cs.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

public void Connect() throws NumberFormatException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

public String SendMessage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     {


         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
         Date date = new Date();
         String getdate=(dateFormat.format(date));

            String content = text.getText();                
            String from = String.format(user.getText());
            String all = "START:" + getdate + ":" + from + ":"+"MESSAGE:" + content + ":END";
            //textarea.setText(all);
             try {
            out.write(all);
             out.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return all;

}
```

Comment: Try slimming this down. You should only need a handful of lines to connect to the server and send a line of text. Write [a simple program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that does that and see whether or not it works. You should also tell us exactly what happens when you try to connect to a different machine, what sort of error you get.

Comment: it simply says connection refused, but whenI connect to server running on same machine with local host, it connects and messages are sent and received

Comment: Have you tried the simple program? You need one line of code to create the socket, one to get the OutputStreamWriter, and one to write a sample message through it. Plus boilerplate exception handling and closing resources. Really simple and might help you figure things out. Unfortunately nobody here can just run your code and figure out what's wrong... (because we don't have your server).

Comment: For that matter, did you write the server? Are you sure the problem is in the client and not in the server?

Comment: I have written the server and my server works perfectly, it is connecting to clients outside the local host

Comment: What clients? I thought the whole point of this question was that clients weren't able to connect.

Comment: the clients are able to connect to my server, but my client is only able to connect to server running on local host, it is not connecting to servers running on outside local host

Comment: You *just* said the server connects to clients outside localhost.